# Intellij : issue with Mockito library (is it corrupted ?)

Tags: intellij-idea

I've been using Intellij and Mockito for years with no issue, but I have a problem on one of my Gradle projects where some parts of Mockito are not recognized as expected, which makes it painful to use.

First of all, when I build my project with Gradle from the command line, I don't have any issue, so it seems to really be a problem with Intellij (I am using latest community edition version, 2020.2.3) .

My first issue was that Mockito was not found at all : thinking that the lib was maybe corrupted somehow, I deleted it from gradle cache folder, where it was stored, so that it would get downloaded again.

Now it seems a little bit better : Mockito is found. However, Intellij will not find the `thenReturn` method on `Mockito.when` :

[image]

When I try to see Mockito's source code, I get this `library source code does not match the bytecode`, so maybe there's some inconsistency somewhere.. :

[image]

I cleared Intellij cache and restarted, but I still have the same issue. I have tried to clone and build the project in another directory (ie another Intellij project), but I have the exact same issue.

I am using Gradle 6.5.

Mockito version that comes is the 3.3.3, through spring-boot-starter-test (I am using the 2.3.5.RELEASE).
If I override this by declaring myself Mockito, in version 3.2.0 for example, then I dont have the problem anymore.
If I upgrade to Spring Boot 2.4.0, then Mockito 3.6.0 comes, and I don't have the problem..

so it seems to really be related to the Mockito 3.3.3 version I am using..

Is there something more I could do ?

Comment: Can you link your version of mockito or the grade dependency in the question?

Comment: I edited my question with the details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up downloading manually the jar from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mockito/mockito-core/3.3.3/ and replaced the jar that was used by my project in .gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.mockito\mockito-core\3.3.3\ , and it seems to be working.

I will do more tests to understand where the corrupted version got download from.